# Why is QueryInterface() returning E_INVALIDARG?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directsound

I was coding a project and I came across a bug where `QueryInterface()` was returning `E_INVALIDARG`, I don't know which argument is invalid because both arguments are simple enough, am I overlooking something simple or what?

The bit that that is failing comes from Microsoft themselves specifically [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee416361(v=vs.85)), if I'm doing something totally wrong tell me

```
HRESULT CreateSecondaryBuffer(LPDIRECTSOUND8 lpDirectSound, LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER8* ppDsb8, LPCWSTR lpName) {
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
    DSBUFFERDESC dsbdesc;
    LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER pDsb = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = 0;

    void* lpRes;
    HRSRC hResInfo;
    HGLOBAL hRes;

    LPVOID lpvWrite;
    DWORD  dwLength;

    waveFile myWave;
    memset(&myWave, 0, sizeof(waveFile));
    // Find the WAVE resource. 

    hResInfo = FindResource(wc.hInstance, lpName, L"WAVE");
    if (hResInfo == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    // Load the WAVE resource. 

    hRes = LoadResource(wc.hInstance, hResInfo);
    if (hRes == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    // Lock the WAVE resource and play it. 

    lpRes = LockResource(hRes);
    char* wavMem = static_cast<char*>(lpRes);
    memcpy(&myWave, wavMem, 36);
    wavMem += 36;
    

    while (myWave.Subchunk2ID[0] != 'd' && myWave.Subchunk2ID[1] != 'a' && myWave.Subchunk2ID[2] != 't' && myWave.Subchunk2ID[3] != 'a') {
        memcpy(&myWave.Subchunk2ID, wavMem, 8);
        if (myWave.Subchunk2ID[0] != 'd' && myWave.Subchunk2ID[1] != 'a' && myWave.Subchunk2ID[2] != 't' && myWave.Subchunk2ID[3] != 'a') {
            wavMem += myWave.Subchunk2Size;
            wavMem += 8;
        }
    }
    wavMem += 8;

    char* soundData = new char[myWave.Subchunk2Size];
    memcpy(soundData, wavMem, myWave.Subchunk2Size);
    FreeResource(hRes);

    // Set up WAV format structure. 

    memset(&wfx, 0, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wfx.nChannels = myWave.NumChannels;
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = myWave.SampleRate;
    wfx.nBlockAlign = myWave.BlockAlign;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nSamplesPerSec * wfx.nBlockAlign;
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = myWave.BitsPerSample;

    // Set up DSBUFFERDESC structure. 

    memset(&dsbdesc, 0, sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC));
    dsbdesc.dwSize = sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC);
    dsbdesc.dwFlags =
         DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME | DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS;
    dsbdesc.dwBufferBytes = myWave.Subchunk2Size;
    dsbdesc.lpwfxFormat = &wfx;

    hr = lpDirectSound->CreateSoundBuffer(&dsbdesc, &pDsb, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (DS_OK == pDsb->Lock(
            0,          // Offset at which to start lock.
            0,          // Size of lock; ignored because of flag.
            &lpvWrite,  // Gets address of first part of lock.
            &dwLength,  // Gets size of first part of lock.
            NULL,       // Address of wraparound not needed. 
            NULL,       // Size of wraparound not needed.
            DSBLOCK_ENTIREBUFFER))  // Flag.
        {
            memcpy(lpvWrite, soundData, dwLength);
            pDsb->Unlock(
                lpvWrite,   // Address of lock start.
                dwLength,   // Size of lock.
                NULL,       // No wraparound portion.
                0);         // No wraparound size.
        }
        hr = pDsb->QueryInterface(IID_IDirectSoundBuffer8, (LPVOID*)ppDsb8);
        pDsb->Release();
    }

    delete[] soundData;
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: `LPDIRECTSOUND8 lpDevice;`
`LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER8* pMainSecondaryBuffer;`
`CreateSecondaryBuffer(lpDevice, pMainSecondaryBuffer, L"mainSong");`

Comment: when i try to send `&pMainSecondaryBuffer` the compiler doesn't like it and wont compile

Comment: That is because you have declared `pMainSecondaryBuffer` incorrectly. You have 1 too many levels of indirection.

Comment: There's really no reason at all to use DirectSound these days unless you are targeting Windows XP. Take look at [WASPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi) if you just and/or [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-introduction).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn is XAudio2 as low level as DirectSound

Comment: DirectSound isn't "low-level" like it was back in the Windows 98/ME days. As of Windows Vista, all audio on the system goes through WASAPI for final output.. DirectSound and XAudio2 are both software mixers that send their output via WASAPI, but XAudio2's design is much more modern and avoids lots of data copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 parameters to `QueryInterface()` for `E_INVALIDARG` to complain about, and offhand they look fine to me inside of your `CreateSecondaryBuffer()` function.  The 1st parameter is being passed a hard-coded IID, so the problem has to be with the 2nd parameter, which expects to be passed a pointer to (in this case) an `IDirectSoundBuffer8*` variable that `QueryInterface()` can write the memory address of a `DirectSoundBuffer8` object into.  So most likely, the `ppDsb8` parameter of your `CreateSecondaryBuffer()` function is not being passed a valid pointer to a `IDirectSoundBuffer8*` variable, like you are expecting.

**UPDATE:** After seeing your added comment, you are indeed passing an invalid pointer to the `ppDsb8` parameter of `CreateSecondaryBuffer()`. The caller's `pMainSecondaryBuffer` pointer is being declared incorrectly, and is *uninitialized* when passed to `CreateSecondaryBuffer()`, so you are passing a bad pointer to `QueryInterface()`, hence the `E_INVALIDARG` error.

Use this instead:

```cpp
LPDIRECTSOUND8 lpDevice = ...; // <-- make sure it points to a valid device object...
LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER8 pMainSecondaryBuffer;
CreateSecondaryBuffer(lpDevice, &pMainSecondaryBuffer, L"mainSong");
```

Comment: `lpDevice` and `pMainSecondaryBuffer` are 2 different types of objects and wont work as you are trying to say, `lpDevice` is a `device` object that is used to create a new `buffer` object, the compiler doesnt like `LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER8* pMainSecondaryBuffer = &lpDevice;` and it doesnt like `CreateSecondaryBuffer(lpDevice, &lpDevice, L"mainSong");` and if i initialize `LPDIRECTSOUNDBUFFER8* pMainSecondaryBuffer` to `NULL` it still doesn't work

Comment: "*`lpDevice` and `pMainSecondaryBuffer` are 2 different types of objects and wont work as you are trying to say,*" - I just realized that.  I have fixed it in my answer.